# How to filter relation members in Overpass

Tags: overpass-api

My final goal is to get country borders from OSM via Overpass API.
I know my country's relation object id - http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/59065 - and can get its details with the following query:

```
[out:json];
  rel(59065);
out body;
```

The relation members list contains ways (which comprise the country border) as well as some other nodes and relations.
How can I filter relation members to leave only way elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot reduce the output of the relation itself (it will always include all elements). However, you can specify to only return ways, which are included in a relation:

```
[out:json];
rel(59065);
way(r);
out geom;
```

Try it in overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/c0l and press "Run"

Comment: What about only polygons of a relation?