# Exclude (filter) relation members by type or role

Tags: overpass-api

The set `relation["border_type"="suburb"]` before recursing contains `node` members with `role=admin_center`, e.g.:

```
{
    "type": "relation",
    "id": 1234,
    "members": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "ref": 1234,
            "role": "admin_centre"
        },
        {
            "type": "way",
            "ref": 1234,
            "role": "outer"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "tags": {
        "border_type": "suburb",
        "boundary": "administrative",
        "type": "boundary",
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I remove these, or rather, how can I modify the query so that only `way` members remain?

If I add `way(r);` as suggested in [How to filter relation members in Overpass](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166329/how-to-filter-relation-members-in-overpass), I lose the relations.

My attempt at subtraction with `(relation["border_type"="suburb"](area.searchArea); - node(r:"admin_centre"););` does not eliminate the nodes in question either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtering relation members by object type is currently not supported. However, you could suppress the location information for the node members, while still retaining the overall relation. This way, your query response only includes ids for relation node members, but nothing else.

```
[out:json];
rel(59065);
out;
way(r);
out body;
node(w);
out skel;
```

overpass turbo displays query results as follows:

[image]

Comment: This displays a number of node circles along the border for some reason.