# Overpass: select area without label point

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

With the following query:

```
area(3608398124);
rel(pivot);
out geom;
```

I get the Manhattan area according to the relation `8398124`. The output is a relation with member elements (with geometries) that determine the area shape.

However, there is also a member with `role="label"`, using XML output:

```xml
<member type="node" ref="357644127" role="label" lat="40.7896239" lon="-73.9598939"/>
```

This member confuses the result processing tools, creating an additional geometry object (point). Is there a way to filter these area labels out?

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer in [How to filter relation members in Overpass](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166329/how-to-filter-relation-members-in-overpass)

Query would be:

```
rel(8398124);
way(r);
out geom;
```

Comment: The extra point is gone, but the problem with this approach is that the area is represented by multiple geometries. The approach in the question has the whole area represented by a single MultiPolygon. For my use case, it's one step forward, two steps back :)

Comment: I'm sorry, you need to roll you own post-processing, then. Overpass can't help in this case.